# How to access windows calculator monitor/view screen using perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to use perl to access windows calculator monitor so I can get the result of the calculations it makes and print it to a file.

Is there a way to access the result window?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can achieve something with [Win32::Ole](http://search.cpan.org/~jdb/Win32-OLE-0.1712/lib/Win32/OLE.pm), although I never did it.

But first, why do you need Perl to get result from Calc.exe? Can't you do it all in Perl in the first place?

Comment: I am practicing perl, the idea is treating the wndows calculator.exe as a program to be tested, so the result that are tested are explicitly what it calculates ,

There is no point assuming a result is something and testing it in perl, I'd like to test what I assume should be returned by the calculator and what it actually give.

Comment: @user2893825 That would be good information to include in your question.

Comment: You may be right but my question was clear. Even if it might make less sense. It is for practice, I didn;t want to include extra information, I wanted to keep it simple and clean.

Comment: @user2893825 Then be prepared to get lots of answers and comments telling you that it's a bad idea and that you should just use native Perl math operators.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot
Do you happen to have an advice for a solution for my problem?